# Convert array of ascii numbers into their respective chracters

Tags: java, arrays, char, int, ascii

In this little project for school, I am doing a Caesar cipher.  What will be done is that the user will punch in a word, and it will be converted to an character array, then into its respective ascii numbers.  Then this equation will be performed upon each number:

new_code = (Ascii_Code + shift[A number that the user picks out]) % 26

So far, here is the code I've written out:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Encrypt {


public static void main(String[] args) {

String phrase = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter phrase to be messed with ");
String shift =  JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many spots should the characters be shifted by?");
int shiftNum = Integer.parseInt(shift);  //converts the shift string into an integer
char[] charArray = phrase.toCharArray(); // array to store the characters from the string
int[] asciiArray = new int[charArray.length]; //array to store the ascii codes

//for loop that converts the charArray into an integer array
for (int count = 0; count < charArray.length; count++) {

asciiArray[count] = charArray[count];

System.out.println(asciiArray[count]);

} //end of For Loop

//loop that performs the encryption
for (int count = 0; count < asciiArray.length; count++) {

    asciiArray[count] = (asciiArray[count]+ shiftNum) % 26;

} // end of for loop

//loop that converts the int array back into a character array
for (int count = 0; count < asciiArray.length; count++) {

    charArray[count] = asciiArray[count]; //error is right here =(

}




}//end of main function




}// end of Encrypt class
```

It is mentioning a "possible loss of precision" in the last for loop. Is there something else I'm supposed to do? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `A a; B b;`, the assignment `a = (A) b` loses precision when `((B) ((A) b)) != b`.  In other words, casting to the destination type and back gives a different value.  For example `(float) ((int) 1.5f) != 1.5f` so casting a `float` to an `int` loses precision because the `.5` is lost.

`char`s are 16-bit unsigned integers in Java, while `int`s are 32-bit signed 2-s complement.  You can't fit all 32-bit values into 16-bits, so the compiler warns about loss of precision due to the 16 bits that would be lost by an implicit cast that just shoehorns the 16 least-significant bits from the `int` into the `char` losing the 16 most-significant bits.

Consider

```
int i = 0x10000;
char c = (char) i;  // equivalent to c = (char) (i & 0xffff)
System.out.println(c);
```

you have an integer that can only fit in 17-bits, and so `c` is `(char) 0`.

To fix, add an explicit cast to `char` if you believe that this will not happen because of the logic of your program: `asciiArray[count]` → `((char) asciiArray[count])`.

Comment: So almost like how translating back and forth multiple times from English to Japanese will change the original phrase into something else altogether, because they are two different languages?

Comment: @user1768884, Yeah.  If you cyclically translate "I ate **the** apple." between English and a language that doesn't have definite ("the") and indefinite ("a") articles, you might get "I ate **an** apple." back.  That is a loss of precision.

Answer (score 0):

Just type cast as `char` e.g. below:

```
  charArray[count] = (char)asciiArray[count];
```